# code is not reading executeUpdate()

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am new to jsp. I am trying to insert data into the table through a jsp page. My code is running fine all the values are correctly passing to the statement. But, after the last value it should move to the executeUpdate command but it moved to the return command instead which returns 0 and data does not inserted into the database. My code is here.

RegisterDao.java

```
package RegBean;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author syedahmed
 */
public class RegisterDao {
    public static int register(user u){
      int status = 0;  
        try{
        Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into register(uname,ulogin,upass,Gender,ucontact,Email) values(?,?,?,?,'',?)");
        ps.setString(1,u.getUname());
        ps.setString(2,u.getUlogin());
        ps.setString(3,u.getUpass());
        ps.setString(4,u.getGender());
        ps.setString(5,u.getUcontact());
        ps.setString(6,u.getEmail());

        status=ps.executeUpdate();

        }catch(Exception e){}
        return status;
    }

}
```

process.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import = "RegBean.RegisterDao"%>

<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="RegBean.user"/>

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>
<%
int status = RegisterDao.register(obj);
if(status>0)
out.print("You are successfully Logged in");
else
out.print("unsuccessful");

%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.jsp

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <form action="process.jsp">  
        <input type="text" name="uname" value="Name..." onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>  
        <input type="text" name="ulogin"  value="Login ID..." onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>  
        <input type="password" name="upass"  value="Password..." onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other"> Other<br>
        <input type="text" name="ucontact"  value="Contact#..." onclick="this.value=''"/><br/> 
        <input type="email" name="email" value="email..." onclick="this.value= ''"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="register"/>  
        
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do not you use jsp with servlet?

Comment: Actually I did this task in jsp with servlet... But, i wanted to do this with bean too... I don't understand that when every thing is working fine then why it is skipping only that command.

Answer (score 0):

It's mean that you code executed in the try section failed. Display the stacktrace in the catch section to see errors.

```
try{
    ...
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: apparently it is showing no errors. I put a breakpoints on the line where I wrote the comman executeUpdate(); and at the return command it bypass the first breakpoint and stopped at the return statement. I don't know why it is behaving like this..

Answer (score 0):

problem has been resolved.. there was a mistake in the query..

```
"insert into register(uname,ulogin,upass,Gender,ucontact,Email) values(?,?,?,?,'',?)" ..
```